# use VS 2008 together with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Could I install Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 on the same machine? Any conflicting and any special care needs to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 can be installed on the same machine without issues. I'm doing that myself.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) for more information, and a few caveats.